# Difference between Thread#run and Thread#wakeup?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In Ruby, what is the difference between [Thread#run](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-run) and [Thread#wakup](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-wakeup)?

The RDoc specifies that *scheduler* is not invoked with Thread#wakeup, but what does that mean? An example of when to use *wakeup* vs *run*? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I see that [Thread#wakup](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-wakeup) causes the thread to become runnable, but what use is it if the it's not going to execute until [Thread#run](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-run) is executed (which wakes up the thread anyway)?

Could someone please provide an example where *wakeup* does something meaningful? For curiosity's sake =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `run` and `wakeup` in Ruby is exactly as described in the documentation, although the specifics of the MRI/YARV implementation are not mentioned. This makes sense, as there are other implementations of Ruby, like JRuby, that use "real" threads.

In Ruby, `wakeup` makes a thread schedulable, but it does not run the thread immediately. `run` also makes a thread schedulable, but it runs the thread immediately.

On MRI/YARV, it may initially appear that `wakeup` does nothing. This is because MRI/YARV has a GVL (Global VM Lock) that allows only one thread to run in the Ruby VM at a time and threads are not preempted in a traditional sense, but instead they run until they relinquish control (`Thread.pass`, `Kernel.sleep`, etc.), encounter an I/O wait or an interrupt flag is raised by the timer thread. In all cases, the thread scheduler resumes one of the other currently runnable threads. So, if you call `wakeup` and then either `Thread.pass` or cause an I/O wait (e.g. `gets`), you will see the other thread executing.

On MRI/YARV, `Thread.run` is essentially equivalent to `Thread.wakeup` + `Thread.pass` if there are only two threads. If there are more threads, `Thread.pass` may not necessarily start the woken-up thread, but rather the thread that the scheduler *considers should run next*. This is why the `run` method is necessary, as it both wakes up a thread and immediately runs it, without leaving it up to the scheduler. This is true for all implementations of Ruby, even those with "real" threads.

Comment: Kudos for answering a 10+ yo question. I'm going to give you the award, however if possible - reply back with ONE reason why you'd want to create threads with "wakeup" but never call run.

Comment: @SaadMalik I'm guessing for the same reason thread priorities exist, one could also "ask why would anyone create a lower priority thread"?

Comment: @SaadMalik Another reason is that it enables fine-grained control over when exactly will the other thread execute, which is handy in for example race condition testing, as you can deterministically craft a specific scenario without condition variables and wait traps.

Comment: @SaadMalik Yet another reason is obvious when you consider creating many threads at once - `wakeup` is the only way to really leave the choice up to the scheduler, as `run` would execute each one right then and there.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example to illustrate what it means (Code example from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Threads/Wakeupathread.htm)):

**Thread.wakeup**

```
thread = Thread.new do 
  Thread.stop
  puts "Inside the thread block"
end

$ thread
=> #<Thread:0x100394008 sleep>
```

The above output indicates that the newly created thread is asleep because of the stop command.

```
$ thread.wakeup
=> #<Thread:0x100394008 run>
```

This output indicates that the thread is not sleeping any more, and can run.

```
$ thread.run
Inside the thread block
=> #<Thread:0x1005d9930 sleep>
```

Now the thread continues the execution and prints out the string.

```
$ thread.run
ThreadError: killed thread
```

**Thread.run**

```
thread = Thread.new do 
  Thread.stop
  puts "Inside the thread block"
end

$ thread
=> #<Thread:0x100394008 sleep> 

$ thread.run
Inside the thread block
=> #<Thread:0x1005d9930 sleep>
```

The thread **not only wakes up but also continues the execution** and prints out the string.

```
$ thread.run
ThreadError: killed thread
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that the _wakeup_ causes the thread to become _runnable_, but what use is it if the it's not going to run until someone schedules it using _run_, which wakes up the thread anyway?

Comment: Could you please show an example where 'wakeup' does something meaningful?

Comment: it has something to do with the thread scheduler. this is from the docs: "Note: This does not invoke the scheduler, see run for more information."

Comment: @phoet I'm still curious as to what the _something_ is? Add the correct answer and claim your prize!