# Differences between Thread#run and Thread#wakeup

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Two methods [`Thread#run` and `Thread#wakeup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html) are different somehow, but it is not clear to me. Can someone provide a pair of code with minimal difference (i.e., difference being only the use of `run` in one, `wakeup` in another) that show different results, and possibly explanation for it?

**Edit** As Cary points out, it is indeed a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763593), and there is a good answer there, but now I am not sure what it means to have a thread awaken but not running. How is that different from a thread being in sleep situation?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763593/difference-between-threadrun-and-threadwakeup ?

Comment: I know nothing of threads (on the list), but I found the following explanation by [Mark Slagell](http://books.google.ca/books?id=bKCuEhzyUgMC&pg=PA443&lpg=PA443&dq=ruby+thread+run+vs+wakeup&source=bl&ots=vT0zpUPjGz&sig=gRrd3c0Cw9uYIcFwlsAxA4DmIvI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dQqJUs3-ItG-2wWBxoCQAw&ved=0CHkQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=ruby%20thread%20run%20vs%20wakeup&f=false): "The difference between the two methods is that `wakeup` merely makes the thread eligible to be scheduled (puts it back in line, so to speak), whereas `run` instructs the scheduler to start running it immediately."  Hope this helps.

Comment: like @CarySwoveland pointed out, `run` internally calls `wakeup` but also uses `rb_thread_schedule();` to instantly schedule that thread.

Comment: Sorry, my real question changed as is in the edit. What does it mean to have a thread scheduled but not running?

Comment: @phoet, I presume you mean 'instantly run". It appears that `run` puts the thread at the head of the scheduler's queue, whereas `wakeup` merely rouses it from sleep, without changing it's scheduling priority. Does that sound right?  For anyone who wants to dig into Ruby threads, including the underlying C code, I found [this](http://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/thread.html).

Comment: Adding this link http://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/thread.html that Cary originally posted as it is useful.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yip, that's what i meant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Thread#run and Thread#wakeup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763593/difference-between-threadrun-and-threadwakeup)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question. You cannot schedule a sleeping thread, however you when a thread is awake it can be scheduled to run, even if it isn't being ran currently.

To add to the first part from my understanding of wakeup vs run is that run calls wakeup inside of it, then calls run on it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> what it means to have a thread awaken but not running

When a Ruby thread is made "runnable," it means that the thread has work to do and is not waiting or terminated. This signals to the thread scheduler that it should consider the thread for execution the next time it decides which thread to resume. However, a thread that is only "runnable" may not necessarily start running immediately.

In contrast, calling `Thread#run` makes the target thread runnable *and* makes it run immediately, without leaving the choice up to the scheduler.

On MRI/YARV, because of the GVL and the fact that threads are not preempted, a thread resumed with `Thread#wakeup` will not start executing until the currently running thread (the one that called `#wakeup`) either relinquishes control (e.g., with `Thread.pass` or unwillingly via the Timer thread and interrupt flag), sleeps, or encounters an I/O wait. This is why, on MRI/YARV, `Thread#run` is equivalent to calling `Thread#wakeup` followed by `Thread.pass` (if there are two threads; if there are more the scheduler may still decide to run some other thread despite the woken up one being runnable).